# Angular Material table is not responsive

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an angular application.It was implemented using Angular Material.I have used a table with tag  with 22 column.
Now when I maximize the browser some of the columns are not showing and event in mobile browser all the columns are not shown .
I have tried with the below approach:

1. First I tried with angular material 'sticky' attribute. It is working fine for browser up to width 110%. But it was not working well when I enlarge the browser size.
2. Adding bootstrap and using  but still not working for mobile screen and large screen.

**.html**::

```
<div *ngIf="!loadingAnimation && events.length > 0">
  <h1>View All Events</h1>
  <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
<div class="loading-shade" *ngIf="loadingAnimation" class="center">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="loadingAnimation"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
<div fxLayout="row" *ngIf="!loadingAnimation && events.length > 0">   
    <mat-paginator [length]="totalEvents" [pageSize]="eventsPerPage" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [showFirstLastButtons]="true"  *ngIf="events.length > 0"
        (page)="onChangedPage($event)"></mat-paginator>
  <div class="table-container">

    <table class="table table-hover" mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" (matSortChange)="changeSort($event)">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="status" sticky >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event">
          <!-- <a [routerLink]="['/events/details-events']" [queryParams]="{matchId: event.matchId}" > {{event.status}}
          </a> -->
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogDetails(event.matchId)">{{event.status}}</button>
         </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="eventDate" >
        <th table-primary mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Event_Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.eventDate}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="teacherName" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Teacher_Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event">
          <!-- <a [routerLink]="['/events/details_teachers']" [queryParams]="{memType:'R',memId:event.memId}" > {{event.teacherName}}</a> -->
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog('R',event.memId)">{{event.teacherName}}</button> 
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="school" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> School </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.school}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="address1">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Address1</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.address1}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="address2">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Address2 </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.address2}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> City </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.city}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> State </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.state}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="zip">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Zip </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{ event.zip }} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="grade">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Grade </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event">  &nbsp; {{ event.grade }} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="scientistName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Scientist_Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" >
           <!-- <a routerLink="/events/events-scientists">{{event.scientistName}}</a> -->
           <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog('V',event.scientistUserId)">{{event.scientistName}}</button> 
          </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="instName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Institute_Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.instName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="instAddress1">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Inst_Addr1 </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.instAddress1}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="instAddress2">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Inst_Addr2 </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.instAddress2}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="instCity">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Inst_City </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.instCity}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="instState">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Inst_State </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event"> {{event.instState}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="instZip">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Inst_Zip </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.instZip}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="classSize">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Class_Size </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.classSize}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="shirtSize" stickyEnd  >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Shirt_Size </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let event" > {{event.shirtSize}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

        <!-- <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator> -->
</div>
<label *ngIf="!loadingAnimation && events.length == 0">No events found, please create one!</label>
```

**.css**::

```
table {
  overflow: scroll;

}


.table-container {
  height:400px;
  width:900px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.loading-shade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 56px;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.mat-table-sticky:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.mat-table-sticky:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
td.mat-column-star {
  width: 5px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

th.mat-column-position, td.mat-column-position {
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

I need more responsive approach so that it can works in any browser irrespective of size.

Comment: You would make things much easier for anyone who wants to help if you manage to reproduce the problem on a site like stackblitz. To make it easier, you can start from an example of angular material documentation.

Comment: this the example you can refered.https://stackblitz.com/angular/qyrdpjlvxpo?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.ts.Here I am taking 23 columns and whenever try to increase browser width all columns are  not shown.

Answer (score 13):

For a responsive table with flex you need to use `<mat-table>` instead of `<table mat-table>` .  You don't get auto sizing for content.  Also you need to change all of the rows and header like the `<tr mat-row>`to `<mat-row>`

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-code-display-flex-code-

Comment: does angular material does not make it responsive or can we take the help of bootstrap.

Comment: @Nabel, thanks very much... wish angular-material would update their help docs to reflect this...

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you still want to use table, Another option is to set horizontal scroll for your table in css like this

In your html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="posteddate" matSortDirection="asc">
   ....
```

and in your css

```
 .mat-elevation-z8 {    
    overflow-x: auto;
   }
```

Comment: This is a great answer. If you are implementing this, be sure to add the ```overflow-x: auto``` property on the actual div outside of the table itself, NOT anywhere inside the table tag. Otherwise, you can add it as part of the class of the table, but then the table will need to use ```display: block;``` subsequently setting column widths as static.